# View attachments added through API docusign

Tags: laravel, docusignapi

I'm using the following endpoint to add an attachment to an envelope:

```
PUT /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/attachments
```

Apparently the request goes well because I get this return:

```
 "attachments" => array:2 [
    0 => array:4 [
      "attachmentId" => "656A658D-AD83-438C-B58D-86738486349C"
      "attachmentType" => "png"
      "name" => "asdas"
      "accessControl" => "SenderAndAllRecipients"
    ]
  ]
```

But nothing appears to the signers on the view. Where the signers can download or visualize the attachments that were added through the api?

**UPDATE**

The method to send the attachments:

```
 public function addAttachments($saleContract, $envelopeId)
    {
        $attachments = array();

        foreach ($saleContract->document as $document){
          array_push($attachments, [
              'accessControl' => 'senderAndAllRecipients',
              'attachmentId' => $document->id,
              'attachmentType' => \File::extension($document->storage_file_name),
              'data' => base64_encode(Storage::disk('sienge')->get($document->storage_file_name)),
              'name' => $document->file_name,
          ]);
        }

        Docusign::addEnvelopeAttachments($envelopeId, $attachments);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are Envelope API Attachments and can be access only via API. When you add these attachments via API, then you can access via API only and will not be available on the Signing screen.

These are like metadata available in an envelope which should not be shown on the Signing screen, and can be accessed via API only. [Dev Doc](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeAttachments/get) explains how to read these API attachments

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 
So, there is a way where we add files to an envelope using the API and the signers can access those files from signing screen?

Comment: if you add any documents in an envelope then they will be able to see it on Signing screen. [Examples](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-send-binary) shows few examples how to send envelopes for Signing.

Comment: Thanks right, I'm usign now documents. But now the following error is returned:

`"errorCode":"TAB_PAGENUMBER_IS_NOT_IN_DOCUMENT","message":"The pagenumber specified in the tab element is not in the document that the tab refers to. Tab on Page 3 of Document 1 for Recipient 1`

I use a template id with tabs, can this interfire?

Comment: This is a diff qs, please mark current qs as closed and open a new one with your code and error.

Comment: The only way that works for me was creating the envelope only with the template id, and as a draft add the documents, then send. Creating the envelope with both template id and document didn't work.

Comment: If you want to add Template and doc in a create envelope call then you need to use CompositeTemplate Design pattern to create envelopes. [Code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-adding-document-template) explains how to use Composite Template to send an envelope.